# Interafce vs abstract class in overriding object class methods

Tags: java, java-8, interface, abstract-class

Following code is compiling absolutely fine.

To my understanding it should not be because `Class C` implementing `interface I`

as abstract class fails to compile as well.

```
interface I {
    public String toString();
}

class C implements I {

}
```

Abstract class is not compiling

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public abstract String toString();
}

public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
}
```

Please help me understand this behavior why abstract is not compiling and interface does ?

Comment: the method is actually implemented in ```Object``` and ```C``` is an ```Object```

Comment: Please check the question again, it is failing for abstract class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every class implicitly extends `java.lang.Object`, and `java.lang.Object` implements the `toString()` method. The interface's contract is satisfied by that implementation, thus removing the need for your class to provide its own implementation of `toString()`.

The reason compilation fails for the abstract class is because you explicitly define the `toString()` method as `abstract`, thereby signaling that concrete extending classes are forced to provide their own implementation.

Comment: But abstract is compiling fine , I have edited my question please check

Comment: Yes, it's failing for the abstract class because you explicitly defined the `toString()` method as abstract, thereby forcing extending classes to implement it.

Comment: MyAbstractClass is failing because 'public abstract String toString()' is a new method you created and should be implemented in child classes. But 'public String toString()' in your interface is a method from Object class and you're just overriding it in your interface I

Comment: Thanks got it can you please share this as answer